# Why is SHA256 a signature type option for a multisig transaction?

Tags: multi-sig

In a multi signature transaction, we can define the Signer Type as SHA256 through the Set Options operation

(https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#alternate-signature-types).

Since Stellar uses `Ed25519`, why not use `Ed25519` only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SHA-256 hash signer type is used for [Hash(x)](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#hashx) alternate signature type. Here is how it works:

- You pick a secret `x` - there are no restrictions on the value of `x` but for security reasons it should be a random 256 bit value.
- You calculate the SHA-256 hash of `x` and add it (the hash of `x`) as a signer to the account using [`set_options`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#set-options) operation.

Let's say that master key weight is equal `1`, SHA-256 hash signer weight is also `1` but [thresholds](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#thresholds) on the account are set to `2`. Normally (with a single ed25519 signer) you only need to attach a signature generated using the private key of the account. But with SHA-256 signer you also need to know the *preimage* of the hash (so basically you need to know `x` that when hashed: `SHA-256(x)` gives a signer on that account).

This allows you to implement interesting concepts on Stellar, including lighting network.

Answer (score 3):

The SHA256 signature is one of the *alternate signature types*. You can safely use a public key of any Stellar account as a signer with a [Set Options](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/operation.html#set-options) operation.

Once you add the additional signer account you will be able to use the corresponding private key to sign the transactions on behalf of the source account.