# Alternate signature - hash(x)

Tags: multi-sig, cryptography

This is regarding sha256Hash field in signer operation.

```
let hash = sha256.createHash('sha256').update(message).digest('hex');
```

Here the input parameter `message` should be 256 bit value. Assuming my input is less than 256 bit  (say for example I want to pass "hello" as parameter), what are the possible ways of padding or encoding the data in secure way ?

Answer (score 1):

Which sha256 implementation are you using? Both [sha.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha.js) (bundled with JavaScript StellarSDK) and [native node implementation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto) do not require padding.

Comment: I'm guessing the "256 bit value" requirement comes from this answer: https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/431/111

Comment: Bartek stated that "there are no restrictions on the value of x". So in case of openly available message one can just use `sha256(x)`. If additional security required (i.e. protection from [rainbow tables attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)), then use symmetric encryption (for example, AES) before hashing - `sha256(aes(x, 'my secret'))`. Even simple [XOR cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) will do in this case.

Comment: To clarify here for OP, SHA256 is a function that takes X as an input and has an output that is a 256 bit value no matter the size of the input. Check out this: https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha256-hash-generator/ Thus, you can, as stated above, use anything as x. In practice, as @OrbitLens stated, if you are implementing something like the Lightning Network where you want to use a secret X to unlock an account/transaction, you want to make sure X is not guessable. Ref: http://dev.lightning.community/overview/#multihop-payments